# Create reference to a primitive type field in class

Tags: c#

I have a few classes which have some primitive fields and I would like to create a generalized wrapper for them in order to access their fields. This wrapper should somehow contain a reference to the fields of my classes so that I can read/write the values of these fields. The idea is to create a genralized architecture for these classes so that I dont have to write code for each of them. The classes have fields which have a number in them which will be used as an Id to access the fields.

This is some example code that might shed some light on my requirement. What I want in the end is to change the value of some field in the object of Fancy1 class without accessing the object itself but through its wrapper.

```
class Fancy1
{
    public double level1;
    public bool isEnable1;

    public double level2;
    public bool isEnable2;

    public double level3;
}


class Fancy2
{
    public double level4;
    public bool isEnable4;

    public double level6;
    public bool isEnable6;

    public double level7;
}

class FieldWrapper
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public object level { get; set; }
    public object isEnabled { get; set; }

    public FieldWrapper(int id, object level, object isEnabled)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.level = level;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }
}

class FancyWrapper
{
    private Fancy scn;

    public FancyWrapper(Fancy scn)
    {
        if (!(scn is Fancy))
            throw new ArgumentException(scn.GetType().FullName + " is not a supported type!");

        this.scn = scn;
    }

    private Dictionary<int, FieldWrapper> fieldLut = new Dictionary<int, FieldWrapper>();

    private List<FieldWrapper> _fields { get { return fieldLut.Values.ToList(); } }

    public List<FieldWrapper> fields
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fields.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo in scn.GetType().GetFields())
                {
                    if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(double))
                    {
                        int satId = getIdNr(fieldInfo.Name);
                        fieldLut.Add(satId, new FieldWrapper(satId, fieldInfo.GetValue(scn), true));
                    }
                }

                foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo in scn.GetType().GetFields())
                {
                    if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(bool))
                    {
                        int satId = getIdNr(fieldInfo.Name);
                        fieldLut[satId].isEnabled = fieldInfo.GetValue(scn);
                    }
                }
            }

            return _fields;
        }
    }

    private int getIdNr(string name)
    {
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(name, @"\d+");
        return Int32.Parse(m.Value);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fancy1 fancy = new Fancy1();
        fancy.level1 = 1;
        fancy.isEnable1 = true;

        fancy.level2 = 2;
        fancy.isEnable2 = false;

        fancy.level3 = 3;

        FancyWrapper wrapper = new FancyWrapper(fancy);

        wrapper.fields[2].level = 10;

        // fancy.level2 should somehow get the value I set via the wrapper
        Console.WriteLine(fancy.level2);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

**EDIT: Fancy classes cannot be changed since they are part of an interface!**

Comment: This seems like a very odd requirement. If you could expand on what you're trying to achieve, I think you will get more helpful answers.

Comment: Well its an interesting problem even though its odd! Think in direction of 'Pointers'. I just a have bad interface with these fancy classes which I have to live with. But I am trying to do something smart by achieving a flexible architecture to do stuff with these classes. The field wrapper is an idea since the fields are related to an id (i.e. they have a number in their name) with each class having fields with different ids.

Comment: Why does each class need to have different field names? Why can't you use the same names and create an interface that all of them can implement?

Comment: Please check the question Edit. Fancy classes cant be changed, they are part of an interface that I have to live with!

Comment: How many fancy classes are there? Can't you just create an adapter class for each Fancy class?

Comment: How would the adaptor look like? Thats what I am trying to do with the wrapper class. It does the job of reading the fields perfectly well but writing to them gets trickier. Thats where I am lost!

Comment: How many fancy classes do you need to work with?

Comment: Well in my case it would be three!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many Fancy classes you are dealing with, you could create an adapter/facade class for each the expose a common interface. eg:

```
class Fancy1
{
    public double level1;
    public bool isEnable1;

    public double level2;
    public bool isEnable2;

    public double level3;
}

public class FieldWrapper
{
    private Action<double> _levelSetter;
    private Func<double>   _levelGetter;
    private Action<bool>   _enableSetter;
    private Func<bool>     _enableGetter;

    public double level     { get { return _levelGetter();  } set { _levelSetter(value);  }}
    public bool   isEnabled { get { return _enableGetter(); } set { _enableSetter(value); }}

    internal FieldWrapper(Func<double> levelGetter, Action<double> levelSetter, Func<bool> enableGetter, Action<bool> enableSetter)
    {
        _levelGetter = levelGetter;
        _levelSetter = levelSetter;
        _enableGetter = enableGetter;
        _enableSetter = enableSetter;
    }
}

abstract class FancyWrapper
{
    public FieldWrapper[] Fields { get; protected set; }
}

class Fancy1Wrapper : FancyWrapper
{
    private Fancy1 _fancy1;

    public Fancy1Wrapper(Fancy1 fancy1)
    {
        _fancy1 = fancy1;
        this.Fields = new[] { new FieldWrapper(() => fancy1.level1, level => _fancy1.level1 = level, () => _fancy1.isEnable1, enable => _fancy1.isEnable1 = enable),
                              new FieldWrapper(() => fancy1.level2, level => _fancy1.level2 = level, () => _fancy1.isEnable2, enable => _fancy1.isEnable2 = enable), };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is something what I had in mind ... but still...is there no way to set a reference for primitives in c#? I think in c++ this would be easily possible with pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could invest 5 minutes learning data structures. Consider following example:

```
var levels = new Dictionary<int, bool>
{
    {1, true}, 
    {2, false}
};

if (levels[1])
{
    //will run, because level 1 is true
}
if (levels[2])
{
    //will not run, because level 2 is false
}
if (levels.ContainsKey(3) && levels[3])
{
    //will not run, because dictionary does not contain entry for key 3
}
levels.Add(3, false);
if (levels.ContainsKey(3) && levels[3])
{
    //will not run, because level 3 is false
}
levels[3] = true;
if (levels.ContainsKey(3) && levels[3])
{
    //will run, because level 3 is true
}
```

Comment: Well I added an edit in my question! Have a look. Fancy classes cannot be changed as they are part of an interface and I have to live with them!

Answer (score 0):

That may seem like what you want, but it really isn't. It is extremely awkward on any number of levels. More specifically, pointers are generally rather "Un-C#-like" and having to know about these numbers defeats the point of having separate classes to begin with.

Think closely about what you want to accomplish. If you're having problems translating it into code, we're here to help. :)

Comment: How about a cleverly written Lambda to access these fields at run time without knowing the field names?

Comment: That's reasonably common, but probably overkill for this case- hard to know that for sure, though. Unless you want to explain what you're trying to do, of course. :)